# Way to display image scale in picturebox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, user-interface

I have added image zoom functionality in my picturebox. I would like to display the scale of the image (like in bottom left of maps). How would I accomplish that?

Comment: I think we must know the zoom functionality in order to answer that because you are asking to reflect in the UI the actions done on the zoom functionality you implemented.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Paint` event to draw the scale on top.

Assuming the zoom is symmetrical in x- and y-direction this would be an example:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float zoom =100f *  pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width / pictureBox1.Image.Width;
    // this may or may not be necessary, depending on how to have implemented zooming!
    if (pictureBox1.SizeMode == PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal) zoom = 100f;

    string s = zoom.ToString("#.#")+ "%";
    StringFormat format = new StringFormat()
        { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Far,
        Alignment = StringAlignment.Far };
    Rectangle bounds = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
    Rectangle bounds1 = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
    bounds1.Offset(1, 1);

    using (Font font = new Font("Consolas", 14f))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, font, Brushes.White, bounds , format);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, font, Brushes.Black, bounds1 , format);
    }
}
```

You can pick the alignments to you liking.

Note that I draw the string twice, once in white and once in black, offset by 1 pixel to allow for any backgrounds..

Also note the the `Image` is the oistrich; the landscape is the (unscaled `BackgroundImage`!

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks! This helped.