# Use graphics.ScaleTransform on Drawing

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi, graphics2d

At the moment I develope a ChartControl and it works just pretty well in my opinion,
but now I'm at a point where it would be nice to have the ability to zoom the drawed signal for better analyzing.

At the moment I calculate the needed points like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PointsCount; i++){
    xAxisPoint = xAxisOP.X + i * (xAxisWidth / PointsCount);
    yAxisPoint = yAxisHeight * data[i].Point / Divisor;

    if(yAxisPoint > yAxisHeight){
        yAxisPoint = yAxisHeight;  
    }

    if(yAxisPoint < -yAxisHeight){
        yAxisPoint = -yAxisHeight;
    }

    Points[i] = new PointF(xAxisPoint, yAxisOP.Y + yAxisPoint);
}

if(zoom){
    graphics.ScaleTransform(0.2f*ZoomFactor, 0.2f*ZoomFactor);
}

using (Pen plotPen = new Pen(plotColor, 1)){
    graphics.DrawLines(plotPen, Points);
}
```

But the problem is: When it zooms in, the zoom is way too big and is drawn outside the bounds of my control.

Is there a way to specify an area in which it should be Scaled (zoomed)?

Comment: You are not using the MSChart contol?  [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727380/real-coordinates-for-graph-inside-viewport-relative-to-mouse-coordinates/50730299#50730299) - Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369404/way-to-display-image-scale-in-picturebox/42371927?s=2|43.2851#42371927) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303881/how-to-draw-on-a-zoomed-image/39305038?s=4|38.1119#39305038) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633446/how-to-draw-on-zoomable-image-in-c-sharp-windows-forms/28645474?s=6|36.2500#28645474).

Comment: @TaW I am not using the MSChart because I am an apprentice and should learn to do it my self.

Comment: Also: what is ZoomFactor ? Also: No, the scaling always goes over the whole area. But you can combine drawing in various scales and also set different clipping regions via SetClip; so in effect you can get the same effect.

Comment: You are asking for TranslateTransform.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, can you explain how to use it?

Comment: You don't need my help, it is already covered very well by the MSDN library and Google.  Just query for "c# zoom translatetransform", the first hit already looks very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the final question: *Is there a way to specify an area in which it should be scaled/zoomed?* you need a combination of [`SetClip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.setclip(v=vs.110).aspx), [`TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`ScaleTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is an example.

It uses a

- target rectangle `zoomTgtArea` where the zoomed graphics are displayed,
- a mouse location `zoomOrigin` where the zoom origin is,
- a float `zoomFactor`, a positive `float`.

Initial values:

```
Rectangle zoomTgtArea = new Rectangle(300, 500, 200, 200);
Point zoomOrigin = Point.Empty;   // updated in MouseMove when button is pressed
float zoomFactor = 2f;
```

The trick to zoom in on only a part of the graphics is to display the graphics **twice**, once normally and once with the transformations of the `Graphics` object.

Let's try:

```
private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // normal drawing
    DrawStuff(e.Graphics);

    // for the movable zoom we want a small correction
    Rectangle cr = pictureBox.ClientRectangle;
    float pcw =  cr.Width / (cr.Width - ZoomTgtArea.Width / 2f) ;
    float pch =  cr.Height / (cr.Height - ZoomTgtArea.Height / 2f) ;

    // now we prepare the graphics object; note: order matters!
    e.Graphics.SetClip(zoomTgtArea );
     // we can either follow the mouse or keep the output area fixed:
    if (cbx_fixed.Checked)
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform( ZoomTgtArea.X -  zoomCenter.X * zoomFactor,
                                        ZoomTgtArea.Y -  zoomCenter.Y * zoomFactor);
    else
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(  - zoomCenter.X * zoomFactor * pcw,
                                        - zoomCenter.Y * zoomFactor * pch);
    // finally zoom
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);

    // and display zoomed
    DrawStuff(e.Graphics);
}
```

The `DrawStuff` I used is simple:

```
void DrawStuff(Graphics g)
{
    bool isZoomed = g.Transform.Elements[0]!= 1   
                ||  g.Transform.OffsetX != 0 | g.Transform.OffsetY != 0;
    if (isZoomed) g.Clear(Color.Gainsboro);   // pick your back color

    // all your drawing here!
    Rectangle r =  new Rectangle(10, 10, 500, 800);  // some size
    using (Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 11f))
        g.DrawString(text, f, Brushes.DarkSlateBlue, r);
}
```

Its only extra is clearing the background so the normal drawing won't shine through the zoomed version..

Let's see:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the answer with a few minor corrections

Comment: and the 2nd PictureBox is Set to Cursor Position ?

Comment: There is no 2nd picturebox. I draw it all on the same one. But, yes, `zoomCenter = e.Location` in the `MouseMove`

Comment: Okay then i go to adapt it for my needs, because i need an Seperate box to display and i have DrawLine() but thx very much

Comment: No problem. Just call the same DrawStuff from the 2nd pbox's Paint, using its graphics object modified in a similar way.. - (But of course you always should try to explain your needs as completely as possible)

Comment: Okay thank you, and in my way i think there will be only one PB becuase i draw Directly the whole Usercontrol.

Comment: And also its a little bit Confusing because your Eventhandler is named as pictureBox_Paint and in the Event you are talking about PicturBox2 and you never mentioned how to Display Rectangle r or the ZoomArea.

Comment: Right, a typo. r is meaningless, just part or some random drawing. ZoomTgtArea is the area onto which I want to draw the zoomed part;  size is what you want and the location either fixed somewhere of moving with the mouse. Or you can simply set it to your 2nd pbox's clientrectangle..

Comment: Is there any timer or how do you update the PaintEvent?

Comment: No, I do a picturebox.Invalidate() at various points, namly the mousemove (where I also test the mousebutton), the trackbar.scroll and the checkbox.checkchanged.

Comment: One last Question about this Topic. Is there an option without the graphics.clear because in the Background it removes the complete Grid i've Drawn and I cant move this Drawing to this Function cause of matrix changes

Comment: Not sure what the situation in ypu application is. You can remove it and see what happens. Or, if the grid drawing is in a function you can call it twice, once before normal and once before zoom-drawing, each time passing out the current graphics object.